# edit content issues in latest DNN 7.2.0 upgrade

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I upgraded my DNN to 7.2.0 latest version but when I click on Edit content, in internet explorer, it showed me can not display this page and in chrome nothing happend. I googled for this, some sites told it's for editor, changing editor to  DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider is a solution, while my default editor is DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider. is there anyway to find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered such a kind of problem after upgrade to 7.2.0.
I've only changed the application pool to integrated mode in IIS and it worked.